# Sorting a nested list using only one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I made a nested list `[[name, score]]` like `[['Ashish', 32], ['Varsha', 32], ['Nano', 31.9], ['Sparsh', 40.3], ['Ria', 30.2]]` and i wanted to sort this list acc. to the numbers.

```
a['score'].sort(reverse = True)
```

I tried the above code but it gave this error,

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What should i try?

Comment: `a` is `list` and you are trying to index it by string. To sort the list `a` in-place by score, you can use `a.sort(key=lambda k: k[1], reverse = True)`

Comment: Thanks it works @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what @AndreyKesley said.

Your nested list is **not** a 2d-list with 'score' as the name of one column. It is a list of lists, you cannot just grab the second column.

You can, however, sort by the second item of every element:

```
a = [['Ashish', 32], ['Varsha', 32], ['Nano', 31.9], ['Sparsh', 40.3], ['Ria', 30.2]]

a.sort(key=lambda el: el[1], reverse=True)
print(a)
```

> [['Sparsh', 40.3], ['Ashish', 32], ['Varsha', 32], ['Nano', 31.9], ['Ria', 30.2]]

or the more beginner friendly version without lambdas:

```
import operator

a = [['Ashish', 32], ['Varsha', 32], ['Nano', 31.9], ['Sparsh', 40.3], ['Ria', 30.2]]

a.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(a)
```

Comment: thanks, it works and yeah i forget that it is a list of list and not an array.